# How can I obtain the elements of this tags?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying do a loop for obtain the elements from a list. This is one part of each element in the list element's (the problem is that i do know how select the elements in **produto-nome, produto-preco, categoria e subcategoria**.

```
<div categoria="Carnes" class="panel-product" produto-fabricante="" produto-nome="Contra Filé Maturada FRIBOI Resfriado Pedaço 1,1kg" produto-preco="45.09" produto-qtd="1" produto-sku="0028363" ruptura="Verdadeiro" subcategoria="Carne bovina">
```

I'm using in Python the package Selenium so, to extract from html page this list i use: `soup.find_all("div", "panel-product")`, but after this i don't know how select the elements from the informations described above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default soup.find_all should provide an array of objects containing each element, so it could be achieved with

```
data = soup.find_all("div", "panel-product")
for d in data:
  produtofabricante = d.attrs['produto-fabricante']
  # do what you need here
```

[Check Soap documentation for .attrs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i need, i passed 2 days trying solve this problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted to use `Selenium`, you do not need `BeautifulSoup`. Initialize the selenium driver and get the html, and then use:

```
c = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("panel-product")
```

And then to get the attributes in this class:

```
print(c.get_attribute('produto-nome'))
```

Comment: I think this is right too, but when i use this code:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'`
I receive this error.

Comment: I missed closing print. Look at the edit and let me know